# Gibbs sampler from from $p(x) = C g(x)$ with $C$ unknown and discrete elements in $X$

Tags: monte-carlo, gibbs, metropolis-hastings

By using the Hasting-Metropolis method, is there a way to draw samples from a distribution of this form:
$$p(\textbf{x}) = C g(\textbf{x})$$
For $x$ being two dimensional and discrete. The reason that this problem troubles me is that I can't evaluate the conditional distribution  $p(x_{1}|x_{2})$.

In chapter 12 Simulation by Sheldon Ross he reviews this problem and is using HM method with the transition probalilty $$q(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=\frac{p(\textbf{y})}{nP\{X_i=x_i,j=i\}}$$
Once again the problem is I can't evaluate $p(\textbf{y})$. And to be honest I don't understand Ross' notation nor approach.

Comment: In your last equation you have made  a mistake: it is $j ! = i$ and NOT $j=i$

Comment: If you can compute $g(\textbf{x})$, then $$p(x_{1}|x_{2})\propto g(\textbf{x})$$